# JSON from Snowflake 2

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is a modification of my question in JSON from Snowflake.  I couldn't find a way to edit that question or add to it.  I apologize for it if it is there.

Here is the new data that I am replacing the original data with:

```
insert into test
values ('{"value": 
     {"evaluation_forms": 
      [ {"evaluations": 
       [ {"channel_meta": 
          {"after_call_work_time": ["XXXX"], 
           "agent_first_name": ["KATRINA"],
           "agent_hung_up": ["XXXXX"],
           "agent_last_name": ["COX"],
           "agent_unique_id": ["LO_00130604"], 
           "agent_username": ["X"], 
           "alternate_call_id": ["XX"], 
           "total_time": ["XXX"]             
          }
         
        } ]
    } ]
}
}'
);
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
--  v.value:make::string as make,
--  v.value:model::string as model,
--  v.value::string as "Extras Purchased",
    cm.value:channel_meta.agent_first_name,
    cm.value:channel_meta.agent_last_name,
    cm.value:agent_hung_up,
    cm.value:agent_unique_id,
    cm.value:agent_username,
    cm.value:alternate_call_id,
  cm.*
  FROM
  --  (select parse_json(src) src from stage.intuit_quality_raw_table) t
    (select parse_json(src) src from test) t
    , LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => SRC:value) v
    , LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => v.value) vv
    , LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => vv.value) ev
    , LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => ev.value) cm
```

I get the first and last name of the user (in the form of [" KATRINA"] and [" COX"]...why the spurious space?"), but everything else is null.

Why?

Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the result you want to achieve, based on your sample data

Comment: I want the data that is in the JSON to come out.  CM.VALUE:CHANNEL_META.AGENT_FIRST_NAME CM.VALUE:CHANNEL_META.AGENT_LAST_NAME CM.VALUE:AGENT_NAME CM.VALUE:AGENT_HUNG_UP CM.VALUE:AGENT_UNIQUE_ID CM.VALUE:AGENT_USERNAME
[   "KATRINA" ] [   "COX" ]      That is what was coming out.  I want the nulls underneath everything other than first name and last name to contain the correct data.

Comment: As @NickW suggested please edit your question adding the comment you made. And delete the comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found it.  I'm an idiot.  I say that all the time.  :)